# Deep Copy, JUnit Test Java

Tags: java, junit, deep-copy

I'm trying to perform a deep copy of an object in which the new object is then modified without altering the oringial. To test the functionaility i'm using JUnit to ensure the functionaility works.

The current test is a basically copying the game "Mass Effect 3" and altering the current voice actor.

Game Class

```
@Override
protected Object clone(){
    Game obj = new Game(getTitle(), getLeadVoiceActor(), getRating());
    return obj;
}
```

JUnit Tests

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    p1 = new Person("Mark", "Meer");
    g1 = new Game("Mass Effect 3", p1, 5);
}

@Test
public void testClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    //This works
    Game g2 = (Game)g1.clone();
    assertEquals(g2, g1);
    assertNotSame(g2, g1);

    //This doesn't even though the lead voice actor is now different
    p1 = g1.getLeadVoiceActor();
    p1.setFirstName("Jennifer");
    p1.setLastName("Hale");
    assertFalse(g2.equals(g1));
    assertEquals("Jennifer Hale", g1.getLeadVoiceActor().toString());
    assertEquals("Mark Meer", g2.getLeadVoiceActor().toString());
}
```

The test is failing with junit.framework.assertionfailederror.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your clone is not deep copying, but only shallow copying. Doing just `super.clone()` would have the same effect.

Comment: @madth3 I've corrected those typos. JB Nizet I was following a book that indicates what i did was indeed a deep copy, could you confirm that it is wrong?

Comment: If that's really what the book does, then the book is wrong, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is: *why are the person in the original game and the person in the cloned game the same?*, then the answer is that you're not deep cloning but shallow cloning.

Calling `getLeadVoiceActor()` and assigning the result to the cloned game passes a *reference* to the person to the cloned game. It doesn't make any copy. To make a copy, you would need

```
protected Object clone(){
    Game obj = new Game(getTitle(), (Person) getLeadVoiceActor().clone(), getRating());
    return obj;
}
```

or

```
protected Object clone(){
    Game obj = new Game(getTitle(), 
                        new Person(getLeadVoiceActor().getFirstName(), getLeadVoiceActor().getLastName()), 
                        getRating());
    return obj;
}
```

Note that the use of `clone()` is discouraged in favor of copy constructors. And if you implement clone, than you should use `super.clone()`.

Also note that you wouldn't have to clone the Person if it was immutable.

Comment: As my getLeadVoiceActor() is nothing more than a string. I'm unable to clone it as you suggest.

Comment: How can it be a `String`? You are calling some methods on it (`setFirstName`, `setLastName`).

Comment: Actually ignore me i was being silly i just realised what i did, Thanks JB Nizet. I completely agree with favoring copy constructors but i wish to understand how a deep copy was actually implemented.